# Is this transformation diagonalizble?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The space is 2x2 matrices.

T is a linear transformation as the following:

$$T\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}a+d&b\\c&2d\\\end{pmatrix}$$

I calculated the matrix of T by the standard basis of M2x2 matrices and got:
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&1\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&2\end{pmatrix}

So the characteristic polynomial I got: $(1-t)^{3}(2-t)$

I think T is diagonalizlble, is it true? thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes it is. You can easily see that the basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_1+e_4)$ diagonalizes your matrix.

Comment: Yes it is. Compute the eigenspaces, then u will see it. The dimension of the eigenspaces in minimally 1. So u know that the eigenspace of $\lambda_1 $=2 has dimension 1. (Why?). Now compute the eigenspace of $\lambda_2$=1. Which dimension has this eigenspace? Why u can conclude that your matrix is diagonalizble?